# ActiveX Button to Change the size of a Selected Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 30+ small scatter plots on one page. I am trying to set it up so that if you click on one of the plots with your mouse, it enlarges the height and width by 400% (aspect ratio locked). Can you have it increase the size of any plot that is currently selected by just clicking on it?

If that is not possible, can I tie a single resize to an ActiveX button? I need a single button to work on all plots (whatever one I decide to click on) without needing different code for each chart name.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Would you need to reduce the size of the plot again when you remove focus from it (i.e. when you click on a cell or another chart)?

Comment: It would be ideal. If not I would be good with a reset button that returns the size back to original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no perfect answer to you question. Excel doesn't offer any "OnClick" event that could be used in this case. The best answer I can come up with is to use a macro like the one below and then assign a shortcut or button to the macro. This way when you have selected a chart and press the assigned shortcut or button, the chart will either enlarge or reduce it's size (based on a given threshold value).

```
Sub ResizeChart()
    Dim ChtObj As ChartObject

    'If a chart is selected
    If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then
         Set ChtObj = ActiveChart.Parent

         Select Case ChtObj.Height
            Case Is <= 300          '<~~~ Assign threshold value for when to downscale
                ChtObj.Height = ChtObj.Height * 4
                ChtObj.Width = ChtObj.Width * 4
            Case Else
                ChtObj.Height = ChtObj.Height / 4
                ChtObj.Width = ChtObj.Width / 4
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```